# Onsen UI - lazy repeat using two column items

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, onsen-ui

I have this template

```
     <ons-row>
        <ons-col width="22%" class="card" ons-lazy-repeat="SimilarDelegate"><!--ng-repeat="item in similarResults"-->
            <img ng-src="{{item .thumb}}" class="thumbnail" ng-click="showQuickInfo(item .id)" err-src="img/noimage.jpg" />
            <ons-row>
                <ons-col width="75%">{{item .name}}<br><ons-icon icon="md-star" size="22px"></ons-icon> {{item .rating}}</ons-col>
            </ons-row>
        </ons-col>
    </ons-row>
```

Using `ng-repeat` my items are rendered in a two column row (each row has two items). But my list can go up to 16000 items and `ng-repeat`' performance is not that good even with 300 items. I changed the code to use `ons-lazy-repeat` and the loading performance is now more than fine! but each row now has only one item instead of two. I've been trying to make it two items each row but nothing yet. Is there a way for `ons-lazy-repeat` to accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`ons-lazy-repeat` works only for vertical repetitions.

While `ng-repeat` just puts more items, so basically it loads everything, lazy repeat has a maximum number of items which it displays. So if you scroll down 1000 items you will still have only 100 items in the DOM at the same time. So remembering more complex stuff about how the DOM elements would be positioned if it they had existed becomes something complex. Therefore `ons-lazy-repeat` supports only vertical repetition. That's why  you have probably noticed that it requires to know the height of the repeated element. So basically you cannot repeat items the way which you are describing. However there are still relatively easy ways to get your desired result.

Here are the 2 solutions which come to my mind:

- Easiest solution is just to have the `ons-lazy-repeat` directive for the element which will contain these 2 items. Then everything will be fine. This is how `ons-lazy-repeat` should be used.
- The second one is kind of hacky and I wouldn't really recommend it, but some people like these things. Basically you should be able to cheat the `ons-lazy-repeat` by giving it false values and doing some css hacks.

  For example lets say that you're

  ```
  .item { height: 100px; width: 50%; }
  .item:nth-child(even) { margin-top: -100px; margin-left: 50%; }
  ```

  And your height function can return `50` instead of `100`. There is also a possibility that some of these styles may require `!important`, since the `lazy-repeat` may be adding some inline styles.

  CSS Hacks prevail once again.

But still I would recommend the first solution.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your first solution is what i' ve been trying to do with no success yet. I guess it needs a bit more development which I am fine to do..